# sending a request for a translation using Google Translate V2 API Client Library in java

Tags: java, google-translate, api-key

I got a new API key using create credentials. But I didnt enter any billing details.Then I used the following code to access the translator API in order to translate a text

```
package traanslatorapi;

import com.google.api.services.translate.Translate;
import com.google.api.services.translate.model.TranslationsListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.translate.model.TranslationsResource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class TraanslatorApi {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Translate t = null;
        try {
            t = new Translate.Builder(
                    com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null)
                    //Need to update this to your App-Name
                    .setApplicationName("OCRProject")
                    .build();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TraanslatorApi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Translate.Translations.List list = t.new Translations().list(
                Arrays.asList(
                        //Pass in list of strings to be translated
                        "Hello World",
                        "How to use Google Translate from Java"),
                //Target language
                "ES");
        //Set your API-Key from https://console.developers.google.com/
        list.setKey("AIzaSyCX2O-pteDLJLeMivT47kD9pucEv67QECQ");
        TranslationsListResponse response = list.execute();
        for (TranslationsResource tr : response.getTranslations()) {
            System.out.println(tr.getTranslatedText());
        }
    }

}
```

As the output I got the following

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded",
      "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at traanslatorapi.TraanslatorApi.main(TraanslatorApi.java:47)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

I used this application on the same day that I obtained the key. I can't find the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it another try after entering your billing details. You need to do that before the API will accept your API key.